# appendChild to multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I wanted to populate 2 different dropdown with the same things. However with this code its only populating one of them, and I'm not sure why it wont add it to both

```
$.getJSON('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/db/casters', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var caster1 = document.getElementById('caster1');
        var caster2 = document.getElementById('caster2');
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            var opt = data[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt['caster_name'];
            el.value = opt['id'];
            caster1.appendChild(el);
            caster2.appendChild(el);
        }});
```

It only populates to the second one, and it doesn't make sense to run a second for loop to populate it. I'm not sure what I can do to fix it.

Comment: an element can only be in one place in the DOM. When you append it to something, it removes it from wherever it was before

Comment: You need to `.clone()` one to make a copy `caster2.appendChild(el.clone())` (probably).  You could also use `$("#c2").html($("#c1").html())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to append a singular element to multiple components/other elements. You could make another one and append **that** to the other list.

```js
$.getJSON('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/db/casters', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var caster1 = document.getElementById('caster1');
        var caster2 = document.getElementById('caster2');
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            var opt = data[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            const el2 = document.createElement("option") // like here
            el.textContent = opt['caster_name'];
            el2.textContent = opt['caster_name']; // here
            el.value = opt['id'];
            caster1.appendChild(el);
            caster2.appendChild(el2); // and here as well
        }});
```